# Triple nested object functions js

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have an object mainly composed of functions/ methods, much like this (Which should work!):

```
function thing1(){
    this.thing2 = function(){
        this.thing3 = function(){
            alert();
        }
    }
}
```

But

When I call `thing1.thing2.thing3()`, I get

*Cannot read property 'thing3' of undefined*

complete pseudocode:

```
function thing1(){
    this.thing2 = function(){
        this.thing3 = function(){
            alert();
        }
    }
}

var foo = new thing1();
foo.thing2.thing3();
```

Comment: "*Which should work!*" - well no. What you have written can be invoked as `var o = new thing1(); o.thing2(); o.thing3()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`thing2` doesn't return anything which results in returning `undefined`.

If you want to write chained functions, you need to return `this`:

```
function thing1() {
    this.thing2 = function() {
        this.thing3 = function() {
            alert();
        }
        return this; // chained
    }
}
```

Generally speaking, it's better to assign methods to a functions prototype if you intend to use it as a constructor. You can still chain functions on the prototype.

```js
function thing1() {
}

thing1.prototype.thing2 = function() {
  return this; // chained
};

thing1.prototype.thing3 = function() {
  alert('thing3');
  return this; // you can make this one chained as well, if you like
};

var t = new thing1();
t.thing2().thing3().thing2().thing3();
```

If you want to just create a basic chain without requiring parentheses, you could create a separate [getter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

```js
function thing1() {
}

Object.defineProperty(thing1.prototype, 'thing2', {
  get: function() {
    return this;
  }
});

thing1.prototype.thing3 = function() {
  alert('thing3');
  return this;
};

var foo = new thing1();
foo.thing2.thing3().thing2.thing3();
```

Comment: …and you should not create methods in any other method (than the constructor).

Comment: @Bergi Right. I was in the process of updating when you typed that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Those are constructors:

```js
function thing1(){
    this.thing2 = function(){
        this.thing3 = function(){
            alert();
        }
    }
}

(new (new thing1()).thing2()).thing3()
```

If you want to call `thing1.thing2.thing3()` you should format it like this:

```js
function thing1(){
    this.thing2 = {
        thing3: function(){
            alert();
        }
    }
}

var foo = new thing1();

foo.thing2.thing3()
```

Comment: They don't have to be constructors. Just because you assign a new property to `this` doesn't necessarily means it's a constructor (although that's generally true).

Comment: Ok how would I construct them with the parent is constructed? So I could just call thing1.thing2.thing3() ? Would I get rid of the function(){} portion and just fave it all in a variable somehow?